# ExpressJS and Apache: Sub-routes not working

Tags: node.js, apache, express, proxy

Let me premise that **base routes** *do* work fine, and every file listed below is placed within the root folder of the website.

My `router.js` is structured as follows:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ response: "Server is up and running good." }).status(200);
});


router.get("/user", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ response: "subroute" }).status(200);
});


router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ response: 'true' })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Then of course, in `index.js` ( the main file ) I instruct the `app` to `use` the above router

```
const router = require('./router');
app.use('/', router);
```

On **Apache2 VirtualHost** configuration, I have the following proxy configuration:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyVia Full
<Proxy *>
   Require all granted
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:8443
ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:8443
```

As the title says, the issue is that sub-routes (`/user`) are not working, rather throwing **502 Bad Gateway** error. **POST** and **GET** on the base routes `/` do, however, work fine.

Comment: I believe the issue stands into `ProxyPass` or `ProxyPassRevers` directive as node is not able to catch anything that does not stand in the root (/) route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly enough, the issue turned to be - as I believed - in `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives.

Specifically, you need to add a **trailing slash** at the end of the target host.

**Bad configuration:**

```
ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:8443
ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:8443
```

**Valid configuration:**

```
ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:8443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:8443/
```

Comment: For me your bad and your valid configurations were turned around. I needed to delete the trailing slash to get subroutes to work. I'm using `app.get('/subroute', ...)` directly however, avoiding the full-blown express structure.